# Number of "Nope"-cards played after each other in Exploding Kittens

Tags: exploding-kittens

How many "Nope"-cards can be played after each "Nope"-card?

E.g.:

- Player A -> Attack
- Player B -> Nope
- Player C -> Nope
- Player D -> Nope

or can only 2 "Nope"-cards be played after each other?

Is there a limit?

Answer (score 3):

From the rules of the basic game: "Stop any action except for an Exloding Kitten or a Defuse". Therefor as many as you like, since the Nope card is not mentioned in the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

There is **no restrictions** on how many "Nope"-cards that can be played after each other.

From the [Exploding Kittens rules](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0345/9180/1483/files/EKG-ORG_Instructions_20OCT23.pdf?v=1698873426):

> NOPE (5 cards)
> "Stop any action except for an Exploding Kitten or a Defuse.
> It's as if the card beneath a Nope never existed.
> You can also play a Nope on another Nope to negate it and create a Yup, **and so on.**
> You can play a Nope at any time before an action has begun, even if it's not your turn...

Your example explained:

> Player A -> Attack
> Player B -> Nope (the Attack is cancelled)
> Player C -> Nope (a Yup -> this means the Attack is back on)
> Player D -> Nope (the Attack is cancelled again)

Other Links:
[Exploding Kittens rule page](https://www.explodingkittens.com/pages/rules-kittens)